# Ionic 3 - gradient for Status Bar colour

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Is there a way to make the StatusBar have a gradient background?

The following does not work.

```
statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('linear-gradient(to left, #00bee4 0%, #0091d2 100%)');
```

Comment: You need a capital `S` in `StatusBar`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge sorry should have clarified, I have StatusBar injected as `statusBar: StatusBar`. Calling the method with a regular hex string works.